# "Describe" HTML element (with no ID) in Error Message

Tags: jquery

I have an AJAX process which returns a "payload" where each top level element has an ID which is used to Replace existing element (within the current page) with matching ID.

The "replace" raises an error message if the ID to be replaced cannot be found.

Sometimes the payload has elements with no ID (probably something went wrong ...) so the ID in the error message is "undefined" which is no help.

What would be a good way of "describing" such element in the error message? innerHTML maybe? or some means of navigating up, or down, until an ID is found?

EXAMPLE:

```
// THIS = Element from AJAX payload
strElementID = $(this).attr("id");  
if (typeof strElementID === "undefined")
{
    // Warn if no ID
    myErrorHandler("ReplaceWith content ID not valid [" + "*** DISPLAY SOMETHING USEFUL HERE ***" + "]");
} else
{
    // Replace 
    objJQ = $("#" + strElementID);  // Object to be replaced
    if (objJQ.length === 0)
    {
        // Warn if ID valid, but not matched
        myErrorHandler("ReplaceWith content ID not found [" + "#" + strElementID + "]");
    } else
    {
        objJQ.replaceWith($(this).children());
    }
}
```

Example of payload:

```
<div>
    <span id="FirstName">Fred</span>
    <span id="LastName">Blogs</span>
    <div id="Error">Customer is marked inactive</div>
    <div>Warning: Customer does not have an address <span id="ErrorNo">#1234</span></div>
</div>
```

and page has

```
<body>
    <p>First name: <span id="FirstName">FIRST NAME HERE</span></p>
    <p>Last name: <span id="LastName">LAST NAME HERE</span></p>
    <!-- note there is no element with ID=Error -->
</body>
```

Each ID, in payload, that has a matching ID, in page, is replaced.  I want error logging for anything that is not replaced.  In particular if the payload element has no ID

The id="Error" does not exist in page, but because it has an ID it is sufficient for debugging to get "ID=[Error] not found". But for the second I get "ID=[Undefined]" (or using tagName I get "DIV" - of which there may be many, and its not enough info)

What I was hoping to find was a smart method of displaying enough information for debugging without swamping the error message box.  Perhaps some innerHTML, or maybe a ChildID if I can find one. I was looking for ideas as to what can easily be found that would be useful for logging.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Sorry, I thought question was obvious, appreciate now that it was not. I did do a search, if you can point me at an answer that would be appreciated

Comment: `if (typeof strElementID === "undefined")
{
    myErrorHandler("ReplaceWith content ID not valid, undefined ID for tag [" + this.tagName + "]");
}`

Comment: Thanks.  I don't think I'm going to be able to fix the issue if the logged data is just "<DIV>". But maybe I can't fix it unless I have the whole content, so maybe only solution is to "phone home" with the whole content.

Comment: Something like `+$(“span[id^=Error]”,this).text()+`

Comment: Thanks. That's put me on the right track, I don't do JQuery often enough to know it well. I think `$(this)[0].className` is likely to be useful (when present) in most cases, and probably worth also logging `$(this)[0].outerHTML` - maybe restricting to first N characters

Comment: That sounds about right.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to understand you question :

if your Id is 'anyId'

```
if ($("#anyId").length > 0) {
    //// write a code to replace
}
```

You can do a pre-check  before replacing. So if the id exist then go for replacement. Else dont do anything. Thus preventing the exception. Answer is based on my understanding from your question.

Comment: Sorry to not have been clear. Have edited O/P.  In the "Else dont do anything" case I want to log enough Info to figure out what went wrong so I can fix it.